# Change range of colors in plot(imshow)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Values in my matrix called 'energy' are close enough to each other: e.g. one value can be 500, another one 520. And i want to see the color difference on my plot more precisely. Like for the smallest value in my data it should be the very dark color and for the highest value it should be the very bright color.

I have the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(energy[0:60, 0:5920], cmap='Reds')
ax.axes.set_aspect(aspect=100)
plt.grid(color='yellow')
plt.title('My plot')
plt.xlabel('Length points')  
plt.ylabel('Time points(seconds)')
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=500)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.show()
```

I get the following plot:
[plot of energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yAm6.png)

**Other words i'd love to get this plot more colorful**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a custom range either through a custom colormap or adjusting the range value to show using the keywords `vmin` and `vmax`. For example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
import numpy as np
fig, ax = subplots()
h = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10) * 10, vmin = 0,\
     vmax = 2, cmap = 'Reds')
fig.colorbar(h)
fig.show()
```

Which produces the colors within 0, 2 value

[image]

Alternatively you can rescale your data or adjust your colormap, see the maplotlib docs for more info.